# apps script : xls attach in gmail to google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try open a xls with app script.
I can get the content type of file with:

```
    var attach = messages[j].getAttachments()[0];
    var name = attach.getName();
    var type = attach.getContentType();
```

And I get:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

but, How I can read the information in the cells ?

#### EDIT

If I use

```
DocsList.createFile(attach);
```

the `attach` is added in google Docs list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved uploaded the file with drive

https://gist.github.com/4666836